# Почему исчезает background-image?

Tags: html, css

Если открыть страницу на `Github`, фон появляется и сразу исчезает. А при запуске на `Cloud9` отображается корректно. Браузер говорит:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

```
body {
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url('../images/background_img.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>WeatherFriend</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nulling.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Посмотрите куда идет путь картинки на github

Answer (score 1):

Это значит не совпадает путь картинки в вашем коде с исходным путем расположения картинки. Пропишите полный путь к картинке.